# jQuery onclick set css didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

This is my code

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function skinchange(link){
  document.getElementById('inputtest').value = link;
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('.imgstyles').click(function() {
   $('.imgstyles').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected')
  });
 });
</script>
```

```css
  .selected {
   border: 10px solid #7EBEFC;
  }
  a:hover img.imgstyles {
      border: 3px solid #7EBEFC;
      opacity:0.15;
  }
  a:hover div.textcss {
   display: block;
  }
  a img.imgstyles {
   border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  }
  .textcss {
   display: none;
   margin-top: -147px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
   margin-right: 20px;
    color: #7EBEFC;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inputtest" id="inputtest"/>
<a onclick="skinchange('https://wp-test-hoangxanh.c9.io/wp-content/plugins/hEmbed/skins/gred.xml')"><img class="imgstyles" src="https://wp-test-hoangxanh.c9.io/wp-content/plugins/hEmbed/skins/images/gred.jpg" width="95%" height="60%"><div class="textcss">Gred</div></a>
```

Function set value work, hover work but my selected css didn't, someone help me!

Comment: looks to be working... which part is not working

Comment: some errors? firebug?

Comment: the 'selected' css not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The border rule set by `.selected` is overwritten by the more specific rule `a img.selected`.

So the solution is to create a more specific rule like `img.imgstyles.selected`

```js
function skinchange(link) {
  document.getElementById('inputtest').value = link;
}
$(function() {
  $('.imgstyles').click(function() {
    $('.imgstyles').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected')
  });
});
```

```css
.selected, img.imgstyles.selected {
  border: 10px solid #7EBEFC;
}
a:hover img.imgstyles {
  border: 3px solid #7EBEFC;
  opacity: 0.15;
}
a:hover div.textcss {
  display: block;
}
a img.imgstyles {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.textcss {
  display: none;
  margin-top: -147px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #7EBEFC;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="inputtest" id="inputtest" />
<a onclick="skinchange('https://wp-test-hoangxanh.c9.io/wp-content/plugins/hEmbed/skins/gred.xml')">
  <img class="imgstyles" src="https://wp-test-hoangxanh.c9.io/wp-content/plugins/hEmbed/skins/images/gred.jpg" width="95%" height="60%">
  <div class="textcss">Gred</div>
</a>
```